# Как вывести все договоры, которые были заключены за последние 3 дня?

Tags: база-данных, phpmyadmin

**SELECT `Ном_дог`,`Дата_дог`
FROM договор _
WHERE `Дата_дог`=CURRENT_DATE()**

- выводит поточную дату

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `Ном_дог`,`Дата_дог` FROM договор _ WHERE `Дата_дог`between SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 2) and CURDATE()